# UINavigationBar title text partially appears on screen

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, uinavigationbar

I am creating a `UINavigationBar` programmatically, which is displaying as intended in iOS 7.  However, in iOS 8.x all the text in the UINavigationBar doesn't appear within the bounds of the screen.  One of my assumptions is this has something to do with Auto Layout.

[image: navbar with streched title text]

```
//ViewControllerRootHomeCenter.m
_navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
_navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64);

// add hambuger menu
//...etc etc

[self.view addSubView:_navbar];
```

Comment: Please decrease your simulator size by clicking on window from top menu bar and then check.

Comment: Please check your view frame in xib or storybord. I think it will be of default size(600x600) when created(in xcode 6 and above). Set actual frame or auto layout constraint to fit in all devices.

Comment: @SweetAngel indeed the frame width for the XIB / view for this particular vc is 600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to obtain the screen width this way too:

```
CGRect frame = (CGRect){0,0,CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]),64);
```

Perhaps it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you're not hard-coding the width of the navigation bar.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
```

Secondly, if your auto layout is enabled, make sure there are no conflicting constraints. If it's not enabled, then I don't see why you should be having this problem.

Comment: I tried your above metioned code, but I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Can you update your post with the code used to create the navigation bar?

Comment: yeah I can do that, above is the code I'm using to create and add the navigation bar.